# PHP MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE Help

Tags: php, mysql

I just can't seem to get this query right. Basically I'm taking a csv from a form and trying to load it into the database. I took the majority of the query from phpmyadmin. i should be using the temp file right? here it is...

```
<form name = "price_chart" method="post" action="index.php?option=<?php echo $option ?>&task=complete" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>File: </label>
<input type="file" name="white" id="white"/><br />
<input type="hidden" value="TEST" name = "test" />
<input type="submit" name = "upload" value="Upload File" />
</form>

<?php
}
function complete($option){
$pfile = $_FILES['white']['name'];  
$ptmpName = $_FILES['white']['tmp_name'];
$test = $_POST['test'];
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ptmpName' REPLACE INTO TABLE 'jos_rates_table' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ' ' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'('country' , 'rate')")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        }
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo $num_rows;
}
```

UPDATE: Here's the Error message

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''jos_rates_table' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ' ' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES ' at line 1

Comment: And what's the problem? Error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the slash for the lines terminated clause, otherwise you just added a newline to your query.

`LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'`

Mysql will just get `\n`, but PHP tries to interpret those so you have to escape them.

You may have other issues, but you haven't told us what happens.

Comment: remove the quotes around the table name, make my updates, and try again, let us know.

Comment: thanks Fosco, the error is now... Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE INTO TABLE 'jos_rates_table' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ' ' ES' at line 1

Comment: The escape for the lines terminated by is just \ so wouldnt escaping it be \\? literally the query out of phpmyadmin that works is...   

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/simpleld/tmp/phpoGAzn0' REPLACE INTO TABLE `jos_rates_table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: @Greg Ok I updated that... so what is ('country','rate') doing in the query above?

Comment: that's removed, i'm sorry, ok here we go, so I updated everything and i'm down to this query and error message... 

$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ptmpName' REPLACE INTO TABLE jos_rates_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());


Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 2


Thanks so much fosco

Comment: @Greg there shouldn't be a line 2... do you have 2 backslashes in front of the n for lines terminates by?

Comment: Latest query: $result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ptmpName' REPLACE INTO TABLE jos_rates_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'")or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
}

Comment: the '\\n' throws an error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\n'' at line 1

Comment: So here's the query that works, but it's not replacing the existing table $result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ptmpName' REPLACE INTO TABLE jos_rates_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why are you using that long-ass url for action instead of index.php or just ''?  Also I think you need to specify  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" since it's an upload form for a file. 
Not sure how to just just insert the file, I think you need to get contents of the file, then explode it and do insert

```
$pfile = $_FILES['white']['name']; 
$ptmpName  = $_FILES['white']['tmp_name']; 
$fileSize = $_FILES['white']['size']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['white']['type']; 
$fp = fopen($ptmpName, 'r'); 
$content = fread($fp, $fileSize); 
$content = str_replace("\r\n", "\r", $content);
$Data_Lines = explode("\r",$content);

for ($n = 0; $n < (count($Data_Lines)-1);$n++){
$line =  addslashes($Data_Lines[$n]); 
$Value = explode(",",$line);
...//The you run insert  statements for $Value[1], $Value[2]...///
```

}

Or you can use fgetcsv - check this article: http://www.programmingfacts.com/import-csvexcel-data-mysql-database/

Comment: the long url is because it's a joomla component and the enctype is there it's just beyond the window, you need to scroll right.