# Import CSV rows to SQL (INSERT or UPDATE)

Tags: php, insert, pdo, cron, sql-update

I have tried to program a PDO PHP file to be executed by a cron job. My problem is not the cron job, but the fact that my script doesn't seem to work..

I found this script

```
http://www.php.happycodings.com/Database_Related/code11.html
```

and changed some content. For example I didn't need the mail to sent to me, and I only have one .CSV file. The thing is with this script, that I would like to check every row, to see if it already exists in the database. If so I would like to update the row in SQL if not I want to insert the row in SQL.

It doesn't show any errors or anything, but somehow it doesn't seem to insert any content in SQL. Every time I execute the file it runs through the page and end up blank.. seems right to me, since I have told it to die if an error occurs.

```
<?php 

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data", 'user', 'pass');
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
    die('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
}

$columnheadings = 1; 


$filecontents = file ('../../_resources/_csv/letters.csv');

for($i=$columnheadings; $i<sizeof($filecontents); $i++) { 

    list($f1, $f2, $f3)=explode(";",$filecontents[$i]); 

    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE 1 = '".$f1."'");

    if ($sth->execute() && $row = $sth->fetch())
        {
            $update = $conn->execute("UPDATE test SET 1 = '$f1', 2 = '$f2', 3 = '$f3' WHERE id='".$row['id']."'");


        }
    else 
        {
            $insert = $conn->execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES ($filecontents[$i])');


        }

} 


?>
```

It should be easy to see what I am trying to do in the script, so please tell me what to do, if you have any idea or suggestions.

```
SQL Database

 ----------------
| id | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|----------------|
|  1 | A | A | A |
|----------------|
|  2 | B | B | B |
 ----------------


.CSV File

 -----------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|-----------|
| A | A | A |
|-----------|
| B | B | B |
|-----------|
| C | C | C |
 -----------
```

This means that my script should be able to ignore the A and B already existing in the SQL database and then only insert C.

This is an example of @njk's idea.. But it still doesn't seem to work.. Do I need a server plugin to accept incoming .CSV files?

```
<?php 

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data", 'user', 'pass');
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
    die('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
}


$sth = $conn->execute("LOAD DATA 
                       INFILE '../../_resources/_csv/letters.csv'
                       [REPLACE] INTO TABLE test [FIELDS [TERMINATED BY ';']]
                       [LINES TERMINATED BY ' '] [IGNORE 1 LINES] (1, 2, 3)");


?>
```

Comment: You're not able to use `LOAD DATA`? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114651/php-mysql-load-data-infile-help).

Comment: Actually I just found this easier to understand. And I don't know wether the LOAD DATA Are going to insert when unable to update..

Comment: With `LOAD DATA`, if you specify `REPLACE`, input rows replace existing rows or if you specify `IGNORE`, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are skipped.

Comment: I am still a bit Newbie, so please if you could show me an example related to my current script.?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query and avoid many calls to the server if you use the Replace into function.

```
$conn->execute("replace into test values ('$f1','$f2', '$f3') WHERE id='".$row['id']."'");
```

Comment: Probably you are right about the update, but the script doesn't even insert anything.. I am sure that it has something to do with the scripting and not the statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LOAD DATA`.

This [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114651/php-mysql-load-data-infile-help/679449) will get you started. Take a look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) regarding the syntax and optional keywords that will allow you to `IGNORE` duplicate rows.

Following your sample data, your `LOAD DATA` syntax might look something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
    IGNORE                   # <= Skip duplicate input rows
    INTO TABLE test
    (1, 2, 3)                # <= The columns to insert into
```

Comment: SO I will end up writing my PDO DB connection, the catch command and just this
<code>
 $sth = $conn->execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '../../_resources/_csv/letters.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE test (1, 2, 3)");</code>